# Bash prompt with a 'non' normal character not wrapping new line with long commands

Tags: bash, newlines, chrome-os

So, when typing in long commands, on most of the terminals I use except for UXTERM, the bash prompt will overwrite the text on the same line and won't go to a new line.

This is my bash prompt in the terminal:

```
┌[~] >
└>
```

And this is my bash prompt in my ~/.bashrc:

```
PS1="┌\[$(tput bold)\]\[\033[38;5;32m\][\w]\[$(tput sgr0)\] \[$(tput bold)\]>\[$(tput sgr0)\]\n\[$(tput sgr0)\]└> \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

The terminal that I usually use is terminator, but I tested this on UXTERM, and it worked fine, but using terminator and crostini's default terminal, longer commands do not wrap to the next line.

Comment: It may be the colour codes, not being encapsulated properly. You need to encapsulate them, so that bash will calculate the cursor position properly.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor They need to be encapsulated in `\[…\]`. And they are.

Comment: Try removing various parts of `PS1` until you find which one(s) cause the problem.